# After comfile and installing with pyinstaller and nsis, the following error occurs (ImportError: PiFrozenImporter cannot handle module 'inspect'_

Tags: python, pyinstaller, nsis, python-exec, python-zlib

---

When I tried to run it, something turned off while running it, so I went to the installation folder and ran it, and I got an error as below.

```
This is the full text of the error.
When I tried to run it, something turned off while running it, so I went to the installation folder and ran it, and I got an error as below.

I've never studied Python myself, but I have to make it this time, so I'm making it.

pyinstaller main.spec => success => dist folder created
NSIS => Success => Setup file created inside the project folder
setup file => installation successful => run abnormal after installation
```

This is the full text of the error.

```
[29708] PyInstaller Bootloader 5.x
[29708] LOADER: executable is C:\Program Files (x86)\test\test_contents.exe
[29708] LOADER: homepath is C:\Program Files (x86)\test
[29708] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[29708] LOADER: archivename is C:\Program Files (x86)\test\test_contents.exe
[29708] LOADER: Cookie found at offset 0x89CC8E
[29708] LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
[29708] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Program Files (x86)\test)
[29708] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[29708] LOADER: Python library: C:\Program Files (x86)\test\python311.dll
[29708] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[29708] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[29708] LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Program Files (x86)\test
[29708] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is C:\Program Files (x86)\test\base_library.zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\test\lib-dynload;C:\Program Files (x86)\test
[29708] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[29708] LOADER: Initializing python
[29708] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[29708] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Program Files (x86)\test\base_library.zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\test\lib-dynload;C:\Program Files (x86)\test
[29708] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[29708] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[29708] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[29708] LOADER: extracted pyimod00_crypto_key
[29708] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod00_crypto_key...
[29708] LOADER: extracted struct
[29708] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for struct...
[29708] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_archive
[29708] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod01_archive...
[29708] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_importers
[29708] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod02_importers...
[29708] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_ctypes
[29708] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod03_ctypes...
[29708] LOADER: extracted pyimod04_pywin32
[29708] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod04_pywin32...
[29708] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[29708] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[29708] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
[29708] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_inspect.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 159, in get_code
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod01_archive.py", line 197, in extract
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_inspect.py", line 47, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_inspect.py", line 14, in _pyi_rthook
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 366, in exec_module
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 161, in get_code
ImportError: PyiFrozenImporter cannot handle module 'inspect'
[29708] Failed to execute script 'pyi_rth_inspect' due to unhandled exception!
[29708] LOADER: OK.
[29708] LOADER: Manually flushing stdout and stderr
[29708] LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

Run normally on the source.
I wanted it to be installed and run normally during installation.
But it doesn't work normally.

```
pyinstaller main.spec
```

main.spec

```
block_cipher = pyi_crypto.PyiBlockCipher(key='**test**')


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\01.Workspace\\python\\test_contents'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                    ('./ui/*', './ui')
                    ],
             hiddenimports=[
                    'config',
            .
            .
            .
                    'lib.CommonUtil',

                    ],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='concat_contents',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```